# Xamarin.Forms: Access layout individually when it has a binding context

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a layout with a few elements that get layout binding:

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="1" RowSpacing="0">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Label
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    VerticalOptions="End"
                                    FontFamily="arial"
                                    FontSize="18"
                                    TextColor="#151515"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Text="{Binding title}"
                                    />

                                <Label
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    FontFamily="arial"
                                    FontSize="13"
                                    TextColor="#151515"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Text="{Binding subtitle}"
                                    />

                            </Grid>
```

So I am giving it mulitple objects with different contents set on a variable with the same name and the result is that all layout get inflated with different contents. That works fine.

However, there is a little notification icon to the right of each layout:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ImageButton
                                  VerticalOptions="Center"
                                  HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                  Source="img_notify.png"
                                  Grid.Column="1"/>
                               <!--   BackgroundColor="#00000000"-->                     


                                <Label
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    FontFamily="arial"
                                    FontSize="18"
                                    TextColor="#ffffff"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Text="!"
                                    />


                            </Grid>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Now, once the user clicked on one of those elements, the notify button is just supposed to dissapear, since the user has already seen it.

Therefor I set up a database that stores the name and the subtitle of the ad if clicked and the next time the list becomes visible, each object is checked:

```
private async void ReturnDataBaseToListAndUpdateNotifyButton(List<ListView_Matches> contentOfListView)
{
    List<db_MatchesNotify_Type> contentOfDatabase = await Database.GetIDsAlreadyClickedOn();

    foreach (var o in contentOfListView) // for each match in our list...
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < contentOfDatabase.Count; i++) //... check every object in our database if they match
        {
            if (o.title == contentOfDatabase[i].titleOfAd && o.userID == contentOfDatabase[i].userID) // check if matches then delete icon
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

.. by using nested looping.

Now I know that my database is working fine and that my logic is OK, but u see that in within the last "if" statement, nothing is happening since I dont know how to adress the notification button now.

Bascially, in within the IF (if a match between the data from the list and the data from the database is found) i would need to set the notifybutton to invisible.

But 1.) I cannot access the object by name since the property from a list is not transported to the class but most:

2.) even if I just set it to invisible then ALL the notifybuttons in my list would become insivible. Ofc I only want this particular object on which a match was found to become invisible.

I need to access the layout that has been inflated individually and decided for each new button now wheater it is visible or not.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: if this is in a listview you really need to use binding.  Add a property to your model that can track the notification status.

Comment: I get it, but lets say the binding is called "notifybutton". I would need to be able to access say: notifybutton[2] from a list of 5 maybe and only set this one to invisible. But I havent found a numerator on those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the same way you have set your `Label`s' bindings. The idea is that this `ImageButton` will always be in the layout and you will simply toggle its `IsVisible` property with a binding.

```xml
 <ImageButton
    IsVisible="{Binding IsNotifyIconVisible}"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Source="img_notify.png"
    Grid.Column="1"/>
```

You haven't specified anywhere what your collection's binding context is, but I assume it is some sort of an `IEnumerable<YourItemViewModel>`. In `YourItemViewModel.cs`, besides `title` & `subtitle`, you will have a property `IsNotifyIconVisible` and that way you will be able set it to `true`/`false` on demand.

Comment: Yeah I get that, the problem is more that the contents for the listview are coming from an external server. Once they are downloaded I am checking each row if any of the contents match those from my LOCAL DATABASE. if they do, I want to remove the nofify icon on THAT particual row ONLY . But the data is already set before since it is coming from an external server. Ergo: I need to access each icon individually AFTER the layout has already been inflated...

Comment: Yes, you do it the same way. When you draw the layout, this new property `IsNotifyIconVisible` will be false everywhere. After you get your data, you will find the appropriate `YourItemViewModel` and update this property. I am assuming in each item view model you have some way of getting it from the collection - by ID most probably?

Comment: you need to update your model/VM with the data from that external service - ie, merge the data together

Comment: Exaclt, that is what I would need to do. First it is false everywhere (is fine) and then I set it to true wherever the condition is met to true. See in my questions I already targeted the exact syntax to where the icon would need to be changed. But is just dont know how to adress the layout here...

Comment: You don't need to look for anything in the ListView. You mustn't touch the layout manually. That's why you have a ViewModel. Each item ViewModel will update the UI from the value that you'll update. You will need to find your item like this: `var desiredItem = allItems.Where(x => x.Id == serverId)` After that you will simply change its property like this: `desiredItem.IsNotifyIconVisible = true`

Comment: Gotit. I can simply just check the property of each object and compare it with the database before setting it. Therefore just setting the value to either false or true:)